# VHDL Comparison Operation Not Defined with Looping Counter

Tags: loops, generics, vhdl, ram

I've been trying to make an SRAM chip in vhdl with arbitrary amount of registers and register size using generics and I've almost gotten it to work except for the addressing part.

To make an arbitrary sized SRAM chip I started by making a unit SRAM Cell (which I tested to confirm that it works) with the following port map.

```
component SRAM_Cell_vhdl
port (
        IN : in std_ulogic;
        Select_Chip : in std_ulogic;
        Write_Enable : in std_ulogic;
        Out1 : out std_ulogic
);
```

The generic SRAM chip has the following port map:

```
port (
    Datain : in std_logic_vector(m-1 downto 0);
    address: in std_logic_vector(n-1 downto 0);
    Chip_Select: in std_logic;
    Output_Enable: in std_logic;
    Write_Enable: in std_logic;
    Out2: out std_logic_vector(m-1 downto 0)
);
```

The way I'm trying to do the addressing is that when it generates the SRAM it checks if the loop counter is equal to the address. If it is it will write the bit to the SRAM cell, if not it will not.

```
  loop1: for I in 0 to n-1 generate
    loop2: for J in 0 to m-1 generate
            SRAM_Cell_vhdl1 : SRAM_Cell_vhdl port map
                (Datain(J), Chip_Select and (I = to_integer(unsigned(address))), Write_Enable and Chip_Select, intermediate_out(I, J));
        end generate loop2;
    end generate loop1;
```

However, I am getting an error at `I = to_integer(unsigned(address)))` telling me that it can't determine the definition of the operation `"="`. I thought that a loop counter is an integer and the way I'm converting the address to an integer it should be doing a comparison between two integers. The other way I thought of doing this is to use an if statement comparing I and the address, but then I fear that it will not generate all of the required SRAM cells.

Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: "The generic SRAM chip has the following port map:"  No, that's a port declaration, the generic clause is missing. `IN` is a reserved word in VHDL and can't be used as an identifier. The type of `intermediate_out`, it's declaration as well as the read selector are missing (actual should be `intermediate_out(I)(J)`). Implicit signals declared for the mode in actual expressions (IEEE Std 1076-2008 6.5.6.3 Port clauses) won't be synthesis eligible. The `loop1` for generate parameter specification is incorrect (`for I in 0 to 2 ** n - 1 generate`). Provide a [mcve].

Comment: A close vote because the question "doesn't appear to be about programming"? So what *is* it about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `=` operator returns a boolean. So, the expression

```
Chip_Select and (I = to_integer(unsigned(address)))
```

when *associated* with an input port of type `std_ulogic` requires a version of the `and` operator with an input of type `std_ulogic`, an input of type `boolean` and a return value of type `std_ulogic`. (This list of types is called its *signature*). No such version of the `and` operator exists.

There is a version of the`and` operator that with two inputs of type `std_ulogic` and a return value of type `std_ulogic`. So, in order to use that, your compiler is trying to find a version of the `=` operator that returns a `std_ulogic`. No such version exists. Hence your error.

Solving this problem is not straight forward, because you'll need an array of chip select signals. So, you'll need *something like* this (as there's no MCVE, I haven't tested it):

```
loop1: for I in 0 to n-1 generate
  loop2: for J in 0 to m-1 generate
    if Chip_Select = '1' and (I = to_integer(unsigned(address))) then
      CS(I)(J) <= '1';
    else
      CS(I)(J) <= '0';
    end if;
    SRAM_Cell_vhdl1 : SRAM_Cell_vhdl port map (Datain(J), CS(I)(J), Write_Enable and Chip_Select, intermediate_out(I, J));
  end generate loop2;
end generate loop1;
```

where `CS` is some kind of array of `std_ulogic`.

Comment: Thank you, I did not realize this. What I did to solve this is that I created a signal `address_comparison: SRAM_total;` Where `SRAM_total is array (n-1 downto 0, m-1 downto 0) of std_ulogic;`. I then used this signal in this statement that converted the boolean value into a std_ulogic value `address_comparison(I, J) <= '1' when (I = to_integer(unsigned(address))) else '0';`

Comment: The question *Is there a way to solve this problem?* which the OP addressed  in a comment and your answer doesn't. Without a [mcve] how do you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your code is not [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would have been more helpful if it was. I guess the below alternative should work.

```
loop1: for I in 0 to n-1 generate
  loop2: for J in 0 to m-1 generate

    signal2 <= Write_Enable and Chip_Select;

    check1: if (I = to_integer(unsigned(address))) generate
      signal1 <= Chip_Select and std_ulogic(unsigned(address));      
    end generate check1;

    SRAM_Cell_vhdl1 : SRAM_Cell_vhdl port map (Datain(J), signal1 , signal2 , intermediate_out(I, J));

  end generate loop2;
end generate loop1;
```

Also, I would prefer using **named association** rather than **positional association** in `port map`

Comment: The code above is basically the entire file minus the entity and architecture declaration boiler plate. The solution produced above does not work since VHDL does not allow for conversion from unsigned to std_ulogic. I tried simplifying your code by just creating a signal for the result of `I = to_integer(unsigned(address))`, but that gave me the same error as before.